# Update nth character in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
UPDATE DocArrangement_History
SET TicketNumber = STUFF(14545, 14, 14, ' ')
WHERE TicketNumber = has / in the 14th digit
```

so i want to update my database and remove the '/' in one of our records which contains an '/'. what is the most efficient way to do this? I'm not entirely sure if using STUFF function would be the best.

This is an example of the ticketnumber that needs to be changed

1317023835606/606-607

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Please show some sample data if possible.  Do _all_ numbers have a forward slash, or just some of them?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated, only two records out of 20,000 have the forward slash

Comment: What about replace?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql

Comment: @JoeC I agree, assuming there isn't other information which would make a blanket replacement not work.

Comment: use `right' function TicketNumber = has / in the 14th digit ex:`where right(left(ticketnumber,14),1) like '/'`

Comment: how can i use replace to replace the 14th digit?

Answer (score 3):

Try this one. It will check for the 14th character only, and it deletes it:

```
UPDATE DocArrangement_History
   SET TicketNumber = SUBSTRING(TicketNumber, 1, 13) +
                      SUBSTRING(TicketNumber, 15)
 WHERE SUBSTRING(TicketNumber, 14, 1) = '/'
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work just fine, `STUFF`, `REPLACE` and `SUBSTRING` can do the job.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (TicketNumber VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);

INSERT @Test (TicketNumber)
VALUES ('1317023835606/606-607');

SELECT TicketNumber
FROM @Test;
-- 1317023835606/606-607

UPDATE @Test
SET TicketNumber = STUFF(TicketNumber, 14, 1, '')
WHERE TicketNumber LIKE '_____________/%';

SELECT TicketNumber
FROM @Test;
-- 1317023835606606-607
```